# Why can't I assign a value to a member of the base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class `CPolygon`  which is derived from the class `CElement`.  [ I'm making use of polymorphism here].

```
 class CElement : public CObject
 {
 public:
virtual ~CElement();
virtual void Draw(CDC* pDC){};
CPoint vertices[11];

 protected:

CElement();

 };
```

---

```
 class CPolygon : public CElement
 {
 public:
CPolygon(CPoint mFirstPoint,CPoint mSecondPoint);
~CPolygon(void);
 virtual void Draw(CDC* pDC);                 


 protected:
CPoint mStartPoint;
CPoint mEndPoint;
CPolygon(void);


 };
```

---

When I try to assign an array to the member `vertices` of a CElement object, I get the error: `expression must be a modifiable Lvalue`

```
 CElement* a = new CPolygon(mFirstPoint,mSecondPoint);
  a->vertices=vertices;        //here!!
```

Why doesn't this work??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `a->vertices` is not a modifiable Lvalue... You can't assign arrays in C++, you can only assign specific elements or do a copy.

If you know the size to be `11`, I'd use a `std::array` (or `std::vector`, for flexibility) instead of a C-style array.

Comment: If you need to copy an array like this, try `std::array` which behaves more like other collections than a raw array does.